# SyntaxError: Unexpected token - Jadeify

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, gulp, jadeify

I am trying to use jadeify with browserify but when adding the most simple thing to my jade file it gets the following error:

```
[20:17:23] Starting 'browserify'...

SyntaxError: Unexpected token
```

**Jade**

```
 .jamie
```

**Gulp File**

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var transform = require('vinyl-transform');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
    var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
        var b = browserify(filename);
        require("jadeify"), { compileDebug: true, pretty: true }
        return b.bundle();
    });

    return gulp.src(['./frontend/js/app.js'])
        .pipe(browserified)
        //.pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./app/www/js'));
})
```

If I leave the jade file it will compile into this:

```
    (function e(t, n, r) {
    function s(o, u) {
        if (!n[o]) {
            if (!t[o]) {
                var a = typeof require == "function" && require;
                if (!u && a)return a(o, !0);
                if (i)return i(o, !0);
                var f = new Error("Cannot find module '" + o + "'");
                throw f.code = "MODULE_NOT_FOUND", f
            }
            var l = n[o] = {exports: {}};
            t[o][0].call(l.exports, function (e) {
                var n = t[o][1][e];
                return s(n ? n : e)
            }, l, l.exports, e, t, n, r)
        }
        return n[o].exports
    }

    var i = typeof require == "function" && require;
    for (var o = 0; o < r.length; o++)s(r[o]);
    return s
})({
    1: [function (require, module, exports) {
        /**
         * Created by Hutber on 07/02/2015.
         */
        console.info('jamie');
        console.info('jamie');
        require('../views/index.jade')
    }, {"../views/index.jade": 2}], 2: [function (require, module, exports) {

    }, {}]
}, {}, [1]);
```

Comment: What is `require("jadeify"), { compileDebug: true, pretty: true }` supposed to be doing? Both the module and object would likely just be discarded after the statement completes as neither are really being used.

Comment: Based on [`jadeify`'s docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jadeify#configuration), it's missing the `b.transform(...)` around the `require()` and options object.

Comment: I couldn't find the transform, but i hugely appropriate the help :) apparenlty this helped for me `"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "jadeify"
  ]
},`